# Real light increments using aperture scale in fractional stops

Tags: exposure, light, metering, diaphragm

In the case of using f-number with full stops, the *+1EV* step means *2*light* because the Area (A = πr^2) in the diaphragm is doubled (i.e. *radius*√2*).

However, I don't know why in fractional stops such as *+1/2EV*; *+1/3EV*; *+2/3EV*, the light is not increased *1/2*light*, *1/3*light*, *2/3*light*, respectively. I mean, the radius is multiplied by *√2^(1/2)*, *√2^(1/3)*, *√2^(2/3)*, which means an increment in the Area by *1.41*, *1.26*, *1.59* (resolving the Area equation), respectively.

Why are not taken the real Area/light increments of *1.5*, *1.33*, 1.66 using the radius *√(3/2)*, *√(4/3)*, *√(5/3)* as the real fractional stops of *+1/2EV*; *+1/3EV*; *+2/3EV*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes down to understanding how logarithms work. Specifically in photography, the log base-2 of a doubling ratio equates to a difference of 1 stop.

We use logarithms to reduce repeated multiplication and division by growth factors to simpler linear addition or subtraction of stop values. If you are familiar with the decibel scale, this is the same process, except that in the dB scale, the logarithms are base-10 (and being SI values, decibels are tenths of a Bel—literally *deci* Bel).

So increasing by ⅓, ½, and ⅔ of a stop (i.e., adding EV) is the same as multiplying a light amount by the ratios 2<sup>⅓</sup> (≈ 1.26), 2<sup>½</sup> (≈ 1.41), and 2<sup>⅔</sup> (≈ 1.59).

In aperture terms, as you note, doubling the light means doubling the area. And also you also note, since area is proportional to the square of the radius (*A* ∝ *r*²), then aperture ƒ-numbers increase (are multiplied) by a factor of (√2)<sup>⅓</sup>, etc.

Comment: @RobinHood - Exposure Value *is* a logarithm, they are not fractions of light received, they are fractions of *stops*.

Comment: @RobinHood Because +1/3 EV is an increase of 1/3 _stop_ of light. The term _stop_ specifically means "a doubling of a quantity" in photography. 1/3 of something means that 3 iterations of the 1/3 results in 1 (i.e., 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 = 1). So when it comes to iterated multiplication, what number when multiplied by itself 3 times results in +1 stop (that is, a total multiple of 2)? Well, that's 2^(1/3) because 2^(1/3) * 2^(1/3) * 2^(1/3) = 2^(1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3) = 2^1 = 2. When we say _n_ stops or _n_ EV (because the "units" of EV is stops), we are saying a ratio of 2^n.

Comment: scottbb answered it well, read it again. Example: 3 stops value increase is 2 to power of 3 = 8 times value (as in 2, 4, 8), but it is 3 EV. The 8 is this value, but the exponent 3 is EV. EV increments in steps of log2(2x value). ISO and shutter duration are powers of 2, but f/stops use the doubled area of a circle, which doubles as powers of 1.414. So 3 stops of 2x of ISO or SS (2, 4, 8) is 2 to power of 3 = 8 (value), but which is 3 EV (exponent). 3 fstops is 1.414 to power of 3 = f/2.828, still 3 EV (exponent). See my site at https://www.scantips.com/lights/fstop2.html for more.

Comment: @RobinHood Unfortunately, what you think is intuitive (from your comment, I mean) doesn't work well from an engineering standpoint. Sometimes certain problem domains require a vocabulary that isn't elementary. In order to talk meaningfully in those domains, we have to spend the time getting comfortable with the meaning and implication of the vocabulary. In the case of stops and EV, the vocabulary is math-based, because it comes from optics and power intensity ratios of watts per steradian areas. In all of engineering and science, power ratios are made much easier by logarithms.

Comment: @scottbb Wouldn't it be better if we just can use the series: √(1/2),√(2/2),√(3/2),√(4/2),√(5/2),√(6/2),√(7/2),√(8/2) for the radius length in the +1/2EV stops, which makes the real light of the images in steps of 1/2? Thus, we could use intermediate shutter time and ISO for the exposure compensation...

Comment: @scottbb Wouldn't it be better if we just can use the series: √(1/3),√(2/3),√(3/3),√(4/3),√(5/3),√(6/3),√(7/3),√(8/3),√(9/3),√(10/3),√(11/3),√(12/3) for the radius length in the +1/2EV stops, which makes the real light of the images in steps of 1/3? Thus, we could use intermediate shutter time and ISO for the exposure compensation...

Comment: @RobinHood No, it wouldn't be better. The ratio between the _n_ +1 and _n_ terms in your sequence is √2, √(3/2), √(4/3), √(5/4), √(6/5), √(7/6), √(8/7), ... which eventually only grows by a factor of 1 (i.e., no growth). It's a sequence of diminishing returns. So the increments in terms of stops (EV) between them is 1/2, 0.29, 0.21, 0.16, 0.13, 0.11, 0.10.

Comment: @scottbb please, check the series. Actually, they are (for +1/3): 0.58,0.82,1.00,1.15,1.29,1.41,1.53,1.63,1.73,1.83,1.91,2.00 for multiplying the radius. Their squares give the 1/3 of light received.

Comment: @scottbb please, check the series. Actually, they are (for +1/2): 0.71,1.00,1.22,1.41,1.58,1.73,1.87,2.00 for multiplying the radius. Their squares give the 1/2 of light received.

Comment: @RobinHood You misunderstand, I took the ratio of √(2/2) / √(1/2) (2nd term divided by 1st term), then 3rd/2nd, etc. In order to have evenly _logarithmic_ (i.e., stops/EV) steps, their successive ratios should all be the same value. That is the definition of a geometric series.

Comment: @scottbb I understand what you mean about the geometric series (I also understood how logarithms work, dB scale...) and It is true that it could be weird applying +1EV to the fractional stops would lead to the same scale. However, I propose a more useful method where the definition of the aperture scale would change to the real intermediate partial of light. If I want to use the fractional stops I don't expect using the maths of (26%, 41% or 59%) what happened with the film speed standards... Thanks anyway.

Comment: @RobinHood I don't understand how what you propose is more useful. Useful to whom, or what circumstances? Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to being argumentative. Is it intended to be more useful for photographers? Or manufacturers? (The latter is quite common do have obnoxious nomenclatures for users but perfectly fine for manufacturers. See the different standards for naming/specifying neutral density filters).

Comment: @RobinHood For instance, in your original question, you ask that for when we say +½ stop, why does that not correspond to increasing the area by a ratio of √(3/2). But if it were that way, then applying +½ stop twice should be a total of 1 stop increase, but that would mean the area increased by a ratio of 3/2. So expecting a doubling of exposure (1 stop) wouldn't be achieved because area only increased by 50%, rather than doubling as desired.

Comment: @RobinHood The U.S. system (Uniform System, from England, 1880) basically did that, with aperture values 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, representing actual multiples of exposure increase (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-number#Aperture_numbering_systems ). But it was obsoleted more than 100 years ago by the f/stop system, which had major advantage of being the same exposure (f/8 is always f/8 exposure) on any lens of any size (including focal length, which otherwise would affect exposure), which was greatly more useful to photographers, and has served us very well.

Answer (score 3):

> Why are not taken the real Area increments of 1.5, 1.33, 1.66 using the radius √(3/2), √(4/3), √(5/3) as the real fractional stops of +1/2EV; +1/3EV; +2/3EV?

Because of addition property.

Surely, you would like adding +1/2EV twice to produce +1EV which means 2*light.

Now, if +1/2EV was 1.5*light, then +1EV would be 2.25*light.

Answer (score 0):

[Asked by me on Stack Exchange Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2526557/22007)

> As you know, cameras and other optical applications frequently use the f-stop system. The focal ratio (f/#) set in common usage is:
>
> 1 – 1.4 – 2 – 2.8 – 4 – 5.6 – 8 – 11 – 16 -22 -32 -45 -64
>
> The f-number set is grounded on the geometry of circles. The f/# is obtained by dividing the focal length by the working diameter of the aperture. The resulting ratio is universally used to compare one lens to another with regards to its light
> transmission potential. The above set has a delta of 2X. Each increment going right decreases light transmission 50%. Each increment going left increases light transmission 100%. The basis is; Multiply or divide the diameter of any circle by the square root of 2 computes a revised circle diameter with an area that is twice or half, in other words such adjustment of the diameter of the aperture stop of a camera, doubles or halves the exposing light energy. For this set, each number going right is its neighbor on the left multiplied by 1.414. Each number going left is its neighbor on the right divided by 1.414.
>
> Now modern cameras often need to adjust using a finer increment. Industry practice is to use a number set in 1/2 f-stop increments. The number set is: 1 – 1.2 – 1.4 – 1.7 – 2 – 2.4 – 3.5 – 4 – 4.5 – 5.6 – 6.7 – 8 etc.
>
> The multiplier/divisor is the 4 root of 2 = 1.1892
>
> Often camera lenses require 1/3 f-stop changes. The number set is:
>
> 1 – 1.1 – 1.3 – 1.4 – 1.6 – 1.8 – 2 – 2.2 – 2.5 – 2.8 – 3.2 -3.6 – 4 etc.
>
> The multiplying/dividing factor is the 6th root of 2 = 1.1225
> One would expect that if you constructed a series of circles the delta for the 1/2 f-stop set would be a 50% area change. It is not, it is 41%.
>
> One would expect that if you constructed a series of circles the delta for the 1/3 f-stop set would be a 33% area change. It is not, it is 26%.
>
> I computed revised circle areas using the multiplying/dividing factors, then a percent change. I am surprised by fact that what I thought was 1/2 f-stop increments only yield a delta of 41% and the 1/3 f-stop set yields a delta of only 26%.
>
> Why is this?

[One of the answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2526665/22007):

> You want the area to double when you change 1 full f-stop. If you want to make two steps with the same fractional increase, they should each multiply the area by \$\sqrt{2}\$. In that case, each one is \$\sqrt{2}-1 \approx 41\%\$ larger than the previous one. Similarly if you want to make three steps, each one should multiply the area by \$\sqrt[3]2 \approx 1.26\$ so each should be 26% larger than the previous one.